# Вызвать alertControllet после клика кнопки с возможностью отказаться от выполения кода Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Здравствуйте!
Есть кнопка c кодом, срабатывающая от touchUpInside. Хотелось бы сделать всплывающее окно (alertController), требующее подтверждения выполнения кода (Yes - продолжить, No - отменить) содержащегося в кнопке.

Comment: и что именно не получается?

Comment: Вынести код в отдельный метод и вызывать этот метод по нажатию на YES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Are you okay?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    // Initialize Actions
    let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { (action) -> Void in
        println("The user is okay.")
    }

    let noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Default) { (action) -> Void in
        println("The user is not okay.")
    }

    // Add Actions
    alertController.addAction(yesAction)
    alertController.addAction(noAction)

    // Present Alert Controller
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Ответ взят [тут](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-fundamentals-uialertview-and-uialertcontroller--cms-24038).

Comment: Работает! Спасибо!